# Why are tattoos not allowed in Islam?

Tags: sharia, practical-islam

I heard that Muslims are not allowed permanent tattoos on the body because it hinders water from reaching the skin. Hence making the *Wudhu* and *Ghusl* never valid.

Please quote some references in your answers.

Comment: Well done, you asked indeed an interesting question which unfortunately many of youth are doing that without paying attention to its Islamic problem. Actually I assume it could be considered as quite a constructive and beneficial question. Consequently hopefully youth pay attention to it carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need of reference from hadith or Quran for this issue.

If one's wudu/ghusl will be invalid , then his/her prayers will be invalid.

So, not-only tatto any other things like nail polish which hinder water from reaching the skin would never be allowed in Islam.

Most of the scholars said that tattoo is not allowed since it is a way of changing the creation of Allah.

**References regarding tatoos are not allowed in Islam**:

- [Sahih Bukhari Volume 007, Book 072, Hadith Number 823.](http://hadithcollection.com/sahihbukhari/105-Sahih%20Bukhari%20Book%2072.%20Dress/6856-sahih-bukhari-volume-007-book-072-hadith-number-823.html)
- [Sahih Bukhari Volume 007, Book 072, Hadith Number 815.](http://hadithcollection.com/sahihbukhari/105-Sahih%20Bukhari%20Book%2072.%20Dress/6864-sahih-bukhari-volume-007-book-072-hadith-number-815.html)
- [Sahih Muslim Book 024, Hadith Number 5300.](http://hadithcollection.com/sahihmuslim/152-Sahih%20Muslim%20Book%2024.%20Clothes%20and%20Decorations/13338-sahih-muslim-book-024-hadith-number-5300.html)
- [Abu Dawud Book 028, Hadith Number 4157.](http://www.hadithcollection.com/abudawud/260-Abu%20Dawud%20Book%2028.%20Combing%20The%20Hair/17960-abu-dawud-book-028-hadith-number-4157.html)

Comment: From the hadiths that you mentioned, it seems like this tatooing is forbidden for women only. Is it so?

Comment: @goto, added hadith for those(men/women) who get tatooed

Comment: With something like a plaster cast covering skin, wudu/ghusl are valid by wiping water over the cast. So logically, you might be able to take wudu with a tattoo as well. However, the given hadiths do a good job of pointing out that tattoos are forbidden, at least for women.

Comment: @Muz, second hadith stated is about both men and women

Comment: but tatoo is ink under skin, it does not hinder skin being cleaned.

Comment: @Muslim Oh, ok, I saw the "cursed women who practise tattooing" and missed the "and those who get themselves tattooed". But because of translation in that context, it's hard to say whether "those" is a shorthand for "those women" or means "anyone".

Comment: @Muz pretty sure wudhu would still count over a tattoo. Think of all the reverts that become muslims who have had tattoos before

Comment: "Most of the scholars said that tattoo is not allowed since it is a way of changing the creation of Allah." -- isn't the circumcision even more of "a way of changing the creation of Allah." ??

Comment: @amphibient, if an action that changes the creation of Allah is an order from Allah, that should be done.

Comment: It may be the case that tattooing and other such practices mentioned in the ahadith was prevalent in women folk during Prophet's time, that only they were specifically mentioned. However, the rationale behind its prohibition remains valid and is therefore applied to both the genders.

Comment: @Muslim so you're saying that somebody who has made a tattoo, can never pray again, that is he or she can pray but the prayer will be invalid?

Answer (score 6):

Having tattoos is not haram in Islam (from a shiite perspective, afaik).

As for ghusl and wudu being invalid because water does not reach the part of skin having tattoo is a misconception.

From Wikipedia article on [tattoo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tattoo) (emphasis mine):

> ...  inserting indelible ink into the **dermis layer** of the skin ...

dermis (part of the skin) is below the surface not on top of the skin.[image]
(Source: [Skin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin))

Therefore water does reach the part of the skin having tattoo.,

On the other hand, [temporary tattoo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporary_tattoo) ([henna/mehndi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehndi), Decal-style, etc) could be problematic because, if I'm not wrong, it inhibits water from reaching the skin and therefore would be advisable to not have. Even then it's not that it's not allowed to have, just that you'll have to remove it in case you want to do wudu and/or ghusl.

Now, to back-up the above with a ruling (although indirect):

> If a verse of the holy Qur'an or Name of the Almighty Allah is written or **tattooed** on the body of a person then such a person while doing **Wudhu or Ghusl**, will be required to pour water on that part without touching the writing.
>
> [Fatwa of Ayatollah al-Sayyid 'Ali al-Husayni al-Sistani](http://www.sistani.org/english/book/48/2168/)

This fatwa proves the fact the Wudu can be performed when one has a tattoo.

---

I am unsure about henna/mehndi (temporary tattoo) because it is widely practiced among the Muslim population of the Subcontinent and Middle-East, so I am guessing there would be a different ruling for it due mehndi's material properties. Same could be the case for pen ink because the above stated fatwa also mentions *written*.

Comment: so tattoos which do not have images of animals are allowed ryt? like some design which are not of living things... ryt?

Comment: @servantofWiser cannot say for sure. (I think it is permissible irrespective of it being living thing or not)

Comment: well I think we must think twice before [drawing living things](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/1761/11938) :)

Comment: Tatoo not allowed because it changing the creation of Allah.