# Can Muslims make statues for non worship purpose?

Tags: shirk

Can Muslims make statues of living things for non worship purpose .
 E.g: to beautify a place
Are Muslims allowed to do this or is it completely prohibited?

Comment: [Is drawing people prohibited in Islam?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/869/is-drawing-people-prohibited-in-islam)

Answer (score 2):

Making statues has been discouraged by the Islamic tradition. However, it is interesting to note that in the Qur'an the word Tamathil (statues) has been used twice. Once in a positive tone and once in negative:

1. When he said to his father and his people, "What are these **statues** to which you are devoted?" [21:52](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/21:52)
2. They made for him what he willed of elevated chambers, **statues**, bowls like reservoirs, and stationary kettles. [We said], "Work, O family of David, in gratitude." And few of My servants are grateful. [34:13](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/34:13)

The first verse clearly refers to polytheistic statues.

In the second verse, statues are among those things for which the family of David is supposed to be grateful. They obviously cannot be polytheistic statues. It raises the question whether statues per se are forbidden or not? Apparently the answer is in negative.

Comment: [Is drawing people prohibited in Islam?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/869/is-drawing-people-prohibited-in-islam) same applies for statues....

Comment: @servantofWiser Thanks! The link does not takes into consideration the usage of 'tamathil' in the Qu`ran.

Comment: "tamathil" what is that?

Comment: Please refer to the above quoted verses. Tamathil is the arabic word for statues.