# Is it haram to make art to make a living?

Tags: halal-haram, art

Basically I'm a student and my lifestyle is too busy and lacking the transportation for a part-time regular job. I want to do something I'm good at, but from home. Where I can be my own 'boss' to make some money on the side, which I desperately need. I used to be a good artist, but I had stopped doing that. Now I want to revive it to make money for when I move.

Would it be haram if I had to make art to make a living?

Comment: The basic ruling for producing or selling art should be on this site already (see e.g. [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/869/17702) for drawing and photography), so the only new question here is probably whether your situation amounts to darura (= "necessity"). My guess is that it probably doesn't, but I don't know enough about this to answer.

Comment: its permissible to do abstract art (no people/animals i.e. things with souls) so do that in sha Allah like skies etc.