# Ruling on drawing human beings?

Tags: halal-haram, shirk, drawing

Hello I am a 14 year old muslim girl.I know that drawing human or living things is haram but from one website I found out that drawing that do not have complete features are allowed, so I drew this. can someone tell me if this is permissible because I did not include any facial features nor the hand are visible? Thankyou for your help.

[image]

Comment: I think perhaps it depends on the location of the soul since the discussion below seems to consider that the determining factor. The first two answers seem to be the most relevant: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/869/is-drawing-or-photographing-people-prohibited-in-islam

Comment: So is that drawing not ok? @ninthamingo

Comment: I'm unsure which tradition of interpretation you come from. Erring on the side of caution I would suggest that if you are asking the question, it is troubling your conscience and so it is not permitted.