# Is spawning charecter in game haram

Tags: sin, game, doubts

I’m sorry for annoying but before you thumbs down this please hear me out I played one game where you can spawn characters,animals,objects,etc it is called garrys mod I would like to know if this is permissible to play

Answer (score 0):

This game would not be clarified as 'haraam' if the creations are temporary, you acknowledge that this is a game and that we are all Allah's creations and are obedient towards him. If you are designing a character, this is 100% haraam, because you are drawing something lifely. I am no scholar, so do not take my answer strictly, and please look at the fatwas posted below! The following fatwas may not relate directly to your question, but consider what they have to say and see if they apply to your circumstances. If this does not help, visit a trusted Imam at your local mosque.

Quotes on drawing / creating lively things:

> Ibn Abbas (May Allah be pleased with them) said: I heard the Messenger of Allah (sallallaahu ’alayhi wa sallam) saying, "Every painter will go to Hell, and for every portrait he has made, there will be appointed one who will chastise him in the Hell.'' Ibn `Abbas said: If you have to do it, draw pictures of trees and other inanimate things. [Al-Bukhari and Muslim].
>
> Muslim :: Book 24 : Hadith 5246
> A'isha reported that Gabriel (peace be upon him) made a promise with Allah's Messenger (may peace be upon him) to come at a definite hour; that hour came but he did not visit him. And there was in his hand (in the hand of Allah's Apostle) a staff. He threw it from his hand and said: Never has Allah or His messengers (angels) ever broken their promise. Then he cast a glance (and by chance) found a puppy under his cot and said: 'A'isha, when did this dog enter here? She said: By Allah, I don't know. He then commanded and it was turned out. Then Gabriel came and Allah's Messenger (may peace be upon him) said to him: You promised me and I waited for you, but you did not come, whereupon he said: It was the dog in your house which prevented me (to come), for we (angels) do not enter a house in which there is a dog or a picture.
>
> Aishah (May Allah be pleased with her) said: The Messenger of Allah (sallallaahu ’alayhi wa sallam) visited me after returning from a journey, and I had a shelf with a thin cloth curtain hanging over it and on which there were portraits. When he saw it, the colour of his face changed (because of anger) and he said, "O Aishah! the most grievous torment from Allah on the Day of Resurrection will be for those who imitate (Allah) in the act of His creation.'' `Aishah said: We tore it into pieces and made a cushion or two cushions out of that. [Al-Bukhari and Muslim].

Look at this question, too: [Is drawing or photographing people prohibited in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/869/is-drawing-or-photographing-people-prohibited-in-islam)

https://www.islamweb.org/en/fatwa/402529/designing-games-with-animated-characters
https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/435574/playing-games-in-which-the-character-looks-exactly-like-a-human
https://islamqa.org/hanafi/daruliftaa-birmingham/136553 (This is a much stricter view for the 'Hanafi' sect. I do not identify with it.
https://fatwa.ca/fiqh/video-game-character-customization-making-game-characters-animate-beings/